# Display RabbitMQ messages without consume them

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I'd like in a web page, in an application, list all the messages from a RabbitMQ (with or without Masstransit) queue **without** consume them ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the RabbitMQ web manager to view all queued messages. In the 'Queues' view, click on the queue of interest.  Then scroll down to 'Get messages' section.  For 'Ack mode', select 'Nack message requeue true' (the default), then type a number greater or equal to the number of messages in the queue for the 'messages' value.  Finally click the 'Get message(s)' button.  You will see all of your messages when the page reloads.

Alternatively, you can call the same underlying http api that the RabbitMQ web manager uses from your own custom web-page.

Comment: I know about the manager but  ... I rephrase my question.

Comment: Using the 'Nack' option means that messages are not consumed.  All messages that you see in the view are returned to the front of the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't know is there a way to get messages without consuming on RabbitMQ. If time is not matter, you can consume messages periodically with hosted service and if you want to show messages in your page with an instant way, you can use SignalR or socket connection.